# Using Oracle JDK with Nix package manager

Tags: linux, java, jdk, nixos

Can somebody point me to the correct steps to install Oracle JDK with Nix package manager? I tried the following so far:

1. https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#jdk - oracle is not there
2. `nix-env -i oraclejdk` - package not found
3. `nix-env -qaP|grep oracle` - no jdk
4. https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Java - has no effect
5. https://nixos.wiki/wiki/FAQ/How_can_I_install_a_proprietary_or_unfree_package%3F - has no effect

I did Nix multi user install on Debian as described here: https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#chap-installation. I did not change any configuration, and installation appears to be working fine (e.g. I can install scala, but it uses openjdk). My channels:

```
> nix-channel --list
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting the package from?

Comment: I assumed it's expected to be in the "default" channel added by the installer - a lot of the instructions say that it's supposed to appear once you enable unfree packages, and it is available in [GitHub repo](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/tree/master/pkgs/development/compilers/oraclejdk). Am I supposed to get it from somewhere else?

Comment: You need to get it from somewhere.  The question lists all the places where it isn't.  You need to find a place where it is, and get it.

Comment: Do you know where I can get it?

Comment: Unfortunately, not a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Running `nix-env -i oraclejdk` works for me on `nixos-19.03` as well as on `nixos-unstable`. Is your nix-channel up to date?

For veryifing that you use the `nixos-19.03` channel you can run

```
$ nix-channel --list
nixos-19.03 https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-19.03
```

To make sure, that you have the latest package expressions of your channel run

```
$ nix-channel --update
```

For migrating from an older channel you can run something like

```
$ nix-channel --list
nixos-17.09 https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-17.09

$ nix-channel --remove nixos-17.09

$ nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-19.03 nixos-19.03

$ nix-channel --list
nixos-19.03 https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-19.03

$ nix-channel --update
```

For more information regarding channels see [the docs](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-channels).

Comment: That is very interesting - I already had unstable channel but not that package. I tried adding 19.03 channel as per your instructions, but the oraclejdk still didn't show up. I updated the question with the output of `nix-channel`. Are you using actual NixOS, or just the package manager? I am starting to suspect that there is a difference between the two.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, I'm using NixOS, but there should be no difference in regard to the set of available packages. If you are still on it; Could you add the content of `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix` and the value of `$NIX_PATH` to your answer? Also you could run `nix build nixpkgs.oraclejdk` and see, wether it results in a warning message about their license or if it just says, that the attribute couldn't be found?

Comment: I looked into this again, and it looks like `oraclejdk` can only be referenced using attribute name, not package name. I.e. both `nix build nixpkgs.oraclejdk` and `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.oraclejdk` work, but `nix-env -i oraclejdk` does not. It's somewhat confusing, but good enough. Thanks for your help!